# Spring `@Autowire` field is `null` eventhough it works fine in other classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, null-pointer

Spring `@Autowire` field is `null` even though it works fine in other classes successfully.

```
public class SendRunner implements Runnable {

private String senderAddress;
@Autowired
private SubscriberService subscriberService;

    public SendRunner(String senderAddress) {
    this.senderAddress = senderAddress;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    sendRequest();
}

  private void sendRequest() {
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("subscriberId", senderAddress);
         HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(dataMap, httpHeaders);
         Subscriber subscriber = subscriberService.getSubscriberByMsisdn(senderAddress);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Error occurred while trying to send api request", e);
    }
}
```

Also this class is managed as a bean in the dispatcher servlet :

```
    <bean id="SendRunner" class="sms.dating.messenger.connector.SendRunner">
    </bean>
```

In here i'm getting a null pointer exception for `subscriberService`. What would be the possible reason for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `SendRunner` class a managed bean? To elaborate: Did you make a method annotated with `@Bean` annotation that returns an instance of `SendRunner`?

Comment: Is your `SubscriberService` class a Annotated with `@Service` or `@Component`

Comment: @Naveen Good point too!

Comment: Also i see in the constructor `public SendRunner(String senderAddress) {
    this.receiverAddress = receiverAddress;
}`. I see that we have an `senderAddress` but in the constructor i see a `receiverAddress` unaware where is it defined.

Comment: @BranislavLazic yes. I updated the question with the snippet

Comment: Please add a @Component to your sender class let me just updated it in the question here

Comment: @Naveen sorry that's a formatting error when I posting the question. It is corrected now.

Comment: @JohnDoe921 how are you calling sendRequest , are you creating object with new?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with below code snippet

```
@Configuration
                public class Someclass{

                     @Autowired
                     private SubscriberService subscriberService;

                     Thread subscriberThread = new Thread() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                  try {
                        HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
                        dataMap.put("subscriberId", senderAddress);
                         HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(dataMap, httpHeaders);
                         Subscriber subscriber = subscriberService.getSubscriberByMsisdn(senderAddress);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                          logger.error("Error occurred while trying to send api request", e);
                    }

                                }
                            };

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please annotate your SendRunner class with  @Component or @Service and include the SendRunner package in componentscanpackage

Comment: If possible can you please post your error log here to get more insight into the problem and how exactly you are invoking your thread which calls SendRunner run method

Answer (score 0):

Your bean not in Spring Managed context, below can be the reasons.

1. Package sms.dating.messenger.connector not in Component scan.
2. You are moving out of the Spring context by creating an object with new (see below), 
   this way you will not get the autowired fields.

   ```
   SendRunner  sendRunner = new SendRunner () ,
   sendRunner.sendRequest();
   ```

Just check how I implement. Hope this will help.

```
@RestController
public class RestRequest {

@Autowired
SendRunner sendRunner;

@RequestMapping("/api")
public void Uri() {
    sendRunner.start();
   }
}
```

SendRunner class

```
@Service
public class SendRunner extends Thread{ 

@Autowired
private SubscriberService subscriberService;

@Override
public void run() {
    SendRequest();

}

private void SendRequest() {
    System.out.println("Object is " + subscriberService);
    String senderAddress = "address";
    subscriberService.getSubscriberByMsisdn(senderAddress);
}
}
```

Below are the logs printed when I hit the REST api.

**Object is com.example.demo.SubscriberService@40f33492**

Comment: This class implements 'Runnable'. So the sendRequest(); is called in the run()

Comment: That is the problem than, you cant call and get the spring managed beans from the java managed objects.

Comment: What is the solution for this scenario? I have used the Runnable as i'm making an API request here. How can I access to the service?

Comment: Check the example I implemented , Hope it helps.